# How can I add horizontal swipe to a TabActivity?

Tags: android, swipe, tabactivity

I have seen some similar posts here, but I haven't found any answers. I want to add a swipe gesture to my tab activity, so that I'm able to change tabs with the gesture.

Here's my code:

```
public class Domiciliaria extends TabActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seleccion);

        //ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        //bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#cd3b05")));

        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    setTabColor(tabHost);
                }
            }
        );

        // Tab for primera
        TabSpec primeraspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("info 1");
        primeraspec.setIndicator("Datos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.primera));
        Intent primeraIntent = new Intent(this, Parte_primera.class);
        primeraspec.setContent(primeraIntent);

        // Tab for segunda
        TabSpec segundaspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("info 2");        
        segundaspec.setIndicator("Motivos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.segunda));
        Intent segundaIntent = new Intent(this, Parte_segunda.class);
        segundaspec.setContent(segundaIntent);

        // Tab for tercero
        TabSpec tercerospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("info 3");        
        tercerospec.setIndicator("Examen", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tercera));
        Intent terceroIntent = new Intent(this, Parte_tercera.class);
        tercerospec.setContent(terceroIntent);

        // Tab for Cuarto
        TabSpec cuartospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("info 4");        
        cuartospec.setIndicator("otro", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cuarta));
        Intent cuartoIntent = new Intent(this, Parte_cuarta.class);
        cuartospec.setContent(cuartoIntent);

        // Tab for Final
        TabSpec finalspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("info 4");        
        finalspec.setIndicator("Final", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pago));
        Intent finalIntent = new Intent(this, Final.class);
        finalspec.setContent(finalIntent);

        // agregando TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(primeraspec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(segundaspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(tercerospec);
        tabHost.addTab(cuartospec);
        tabHost.addTab(finalspec);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(true);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(R.drawable.barra_mamei);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(R.drawable.barra_mamei);
        setTabColor(tabHost);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
            return true;
            case R.id.help:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
            return true;
            case R.id.CasoEspecial:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, CasoEspecial.class));
            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        // respond to menu item selection
    }

    protected void setTabColor(TabHost tabHost) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E04006")); //unselected
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fbfbf3")); // selected
    }
}
```

Comment: use this library for achieving that https://github.com/astuetz/android-viewpagertabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the TabSwipe using ViewPager with Fragments and ActionBar.

If you wish to work with Minimum API 11,  the  following  link will show you how. Since API 11, ActionBar has the way to create tabs in application with fragments.

If you need to give support to the older versions, you should make use of [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)
 or [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html)

[Check out this Link as well](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-horizontal-swiping-in-action-bar-tabs-using-viewpager/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best tutorial for horizontal swipe views straight from google.
[Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) 
I would recommened to use `Fragments` and `FragmentActivity` instead of `TabActivity`